# How many active objects can one ActiveScheduler handle?

Tags: symbian

I have a question about Symbian active objects handling. What's the problem: my program runs in 1 thread and have pretty much active objects in it. As per my logs, I see strange pauses in tasks processing. My program have about 30 simultaneously active objects in one ActiveScheduler. Is it okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Symbian Active Scheduler can handle pretty much as many Active Objects as you need.

Obviously, each added active object has a tiny performance impact on the whole scheduler but 30 is well within acceptable range.

You do have to remember this is all based on cooperative multitasking, though. If too many requests get completed too fast and active objects take too long to run, the time it takes for the scheduler to call RunL() on a specific single active object can become unacceptable for your application.